# Is there something like AlarmManager in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to schedule the execution of some lines of code in the future just as [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) does. That is:

- Schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.
- Automatically start the target application if it is not already running.
- Wake up the device if it is asleep.

Of course I would need to have support for iOS.

I found [scheduled_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scheduled_notifications) but it doesn't seem to cover all these conditions.

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flutter doesn't currently provide a mechanism to run Dart code in the background without a `FlutterView`. Follow [issue 3671](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671) for updates.

You probably don't want to launch your main activity immediately when the alarm goes off, because that would be very disruptive, so your best bet for the moment is probably to solve this problem using regular Java and Objective-C code in the standard way.

Comment: As for today that issue is closed and the discussion was moved to [#24278](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24278) with no good multiplatform solution so far.

Answer (score 6):

As of late 2017 we now have an [`android_alarm_manager`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager) package for accessing the Android AlarmManager service, and running Dart code in the background when alarms fire.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not having any luck getting that plugin to work.

Comment: It's expected to work. If it doesn't, please open a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: Got it to work. I needed to use a top-level function. I was using an anonymous function. Its documented too. And makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: @DragonFax can you please provide a working example of using  android_alarm_manager code? I was trying to implement following  documentation, but got message in the Logcat "AlarmService: AlarmService has not yet started." Dont get what Im mising :\

Comment: How about iOS, do you have suggestion ?